# Setting Row Height not working for EPPlus

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

I am trying to set up the height in an existing excel sheet with EPPlus. It does not seem to be working at all. Any idea on what else I could try ?

I have tried setting it before and after initial styling and have tried setting it after filling values but an exception is thrown.

```
    private static void SetStyleForLine(ExcelWorksheet ws, int lineIndex)
    {
        .....
        ws.Row(lineIndex).CustomHeight = true;
        ws.Row(lineIndex).Height = 50;

    }
```

Excel sheet is still showing a height of 15.

Comment: Whats the exception?  It looks like it should work but you may want to paste more of your code since there is not much to go one from above.

Comment: Could you show more of your code?
I had no problem setting the height property of the selected row before or after inserting values.